# creating public database link

Tags: database, oracle, sql-server-2008

i'm trying to create a public database link to an sql server and am constantly getting syntax error. 
This is the command

```
 CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK AMRCMSLINK CONNECT TO "dbacecg" IDENTIFIED BY "@dbac@ecg@" USING "CMSPRO";
```

am getting this error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server RMR, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PUBLIC'.
```

Comment: You are apparently running that while being connected to a SQL Server. You need to run that in Oracle

Comment: Side question, why do you need a PUBLIC database link?